# Accessing float/double list using rosparam

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having a problem to access a float array using rosparam.

I have my parameters inside a lunch file as given below.

max_height: 1
       min_height: 0.4
       debug_windows: false
       debug_messages: false
       camera_param: [543.848868, 0.0, 297.599352,297.599352, 0.0, 543.745831, 240.206525, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

I am able to access all my parameters by following way.

```
    ros::param::getCached("/target_follow/max_height", maxHeight);
    ros::param::getCached("/target_follow/min_height", minHeight);
    ros::param::getCached("/target_follow/debug_windows", showDebugWindows);
    ros::param::getCached("/target_follow/debug_messages", showDebugMessages);
```

can someone suggest me how can I access the list without a nodehandle object;

Regards,
Subhasis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66504/accessing-float/double-list-using-rosparam/) by [Subhasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3414/subhasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to do that as [described here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Subhasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3414/subhasis/) on 2013-07-04**:
Thanks. It works fine now.